# How to restrict space at the first position in javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function

I have the below regEx to allow spaces in the middle of the word.

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-,.;'&/.() ]/g,'')"
```

How do i restrict space in the first position if the input box.
Spaces in the middle are allowed.

Comment: You could call `this.value = this.value.trim();` followed by any other logic that you want to execute.

Comment: I dont want to trim after the user enters. I want to restrict when the user enters space in the first position

Comment: Add this to your element `onkeypress="return event.charCode !== 32 || this.value.length"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate between start-of-string anchor (with `^`) followed by a space, and the rest of your negative character set:

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-,.;'&/.() ]|^ /g,'')"
```

```html
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-,.;'&/.() ]|^ /g,'')" value=" foo bar">
```

Comment: This doesnt allow spaces in the middle of the letters. I want to restrict only in the beginning.

Comment: It should: the negative character set includes a space, so only a space at the very beginning will be matched. (others, like in the middle of the string, will stay there) See snippet in edit, seems to work as expected

Comment: @angie Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802574/476951) . It saves the caret position and doesn't jump to the end of the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use built in String method `trim()`. `trim()` method in javascript removes spaces from the starting and ending of the string.

`this.value = this.value.trim()
 // if you want to apply regex also, you can try the below code
 this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-,.;'&/.() ]|^ /g,'').trim()`

```css
const a = '   hello '
console.log(a.trim())
// hello
```

Comment: This also removes spaces from the end of the string, as well as spaces past the first position, but before non-space characters, which OP didn't say was desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Just `trim` the string before you `replace` it:

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.trim().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-,.;'&/.() ]/g,'')"
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works a little bit like [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801853/476951), but save's the caret position and doesn't jump to the end of the input

#### Edit

Added some visual feedback

```js
;(() => {
  const inp = document.querySelector('#inp');
  
  const nospaces = function(elem) {
    // find spaces at start of input
    const spacesReg = /^\s+/;
    let match
    if (match = elem.value.match(spacesReg)) {
      // save current caret position
      const pos = elem.selectionStart;
      const len = match[0].length;
      elem.value = elem.value.replace(spacesReg, '');
      // reset caret position
      elem.selectionStart = elem.selectionEnd = Math.min(0, pos - len)
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
  
  const onlyAllowedCharacters = function(elem) {
    // search for not allowed characters
    const allowed = "A-Za-z0-9-,.;'&/.() ";
    const notAllowedReg = new RegExp(`(.*?)[^${allowed}]`);
    // prevent infinite loop
    var max = 255;
    let match;
    let blink = false
    // replace one not allowed character per loop run
    while ((max > 0) && (match = elem.value.match(notAllowedReg))) {
      blink = true
      const pos = elem.selectionStart;
      const len = match[1].length
      elem.value = elem.value.replace(notAllowedReg, '$1');
      elem.selectionStart = elem.selectionEnd = pos - 1
      max--
    }
    return blink;
  }
  
  const blink = function(elem, duration = 200) {
    const to = setTimeout(() => {
      elem.classList.remove('blink')
    }, duration)
    elem.classList.add('blink')
  }
  // use function literal to get correct `this` value
  inp.addEventListener('input', function(e) { 
    const nosp = nospaces(this);
    const only = onlyAllowedCharacters(this);
    if (nosp || only) {
      blink(this)
    }
    
  })
})();
```

```css
.blink {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
No spaces at start of input<br>
Only allowed characters a–zA–Z0–9-,.;'&\.()<br>
<input type="text" id="inp">
```